# Uneven ceiling, best way to fix it?

Tags: bathroom, walls, ceiling, trim

Contractor responsible for preparing the ceiling and painting, neglected to mention the ceiling for bathroom is visibly uneven. 7cm difference from one end to the other. Looks also a bit concave. The contractor said it's not his responsibility and blamed it on someone else. Said best way to fix it is buying trims to cover up the edges between wall and ceiling. And advised against tearing it down and starting again, waste of time and still might end up uneven. Is he right?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases a ceiing in an older home if replaced needs to have an attic strongback installed to occomdate the new ceiling.  As a home shifts with settlement of ground and foundation the current strongbacks are compromised.  So when installing ned to old, the old ceiling joists need to be supported.  When the old drywall was removed, the old strongback releases pressure and caused the joists to shift.  So work must be done to the structure of the attic.  It is obvious that the strongbacks and the joists are drooping. Is it the drywall guys fault?  Yes and no.  He is not a structure contractor.  It is the General Contractors fault.  And if the home owner was the GC...it is the inexperience of the homeowner.  When you hire a finisher to repair problems, you have bad results.  In a court situation if you attempt to litigate, the finisher will win the suit as he is there to install the drywall to the existing structure only...He does not have the skills for anything else.

Comment: I told the finisher he should've informed me before beginning his work so I know what to do. Had an argument over it because he sees that I'm protesting over nothing since i shouldn't change anything anyway. I bought the place and remodeling it. The same contractor gave me problems, he finished his work before ge let other contractors finish before him because now some electricity wasn't installed.

Comment: Somewhat interesting commentary on strongbacks, but there's no evidence in the OP's text about the structure of the house, its age, or its settlement patterns. So, saying things like, "It is obvious that the strongbacks and the joists are drooping" is vexing at best. I agree with the latter half of your answer.

Comment: Only way the ceiling would be unlevel is a SB issue as the drywall detaches from the ceiling joist above.This is very common in older homes.A few screws to the existing can be an option as long as the gap is not greater than 1/8th inch.Any larger gap would require a new SB being placed to assist the ceiling in lifting up.In some cases the thickness of drywall is the issue as older homes use a true 5/8 and the only thing close to 5/8 I know of these days is fire code drywall.But if that is the case the mud guy can transition the 2.But in cases of SB failure,the only way to remedy is SB addition

Comment: And in most cases depending on the contract wording, a finisher is generally not an expert at framing and is not even qualified to advise on framing.  A qualified General Contractor is the best option to go with.  You will pay an average of 25% more but do not in most cases have these issues.

Answer (score 0):

No he is not right.  If you want it nice, you can insist on it being right. Don't pay until it meets your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

If your contract stipulated that the ceiling should be level and even, then you should get that.

If it's not in the contract, it's not the fault of the trades.

You could tear everything down and get it perfect, but the cost/results ratio might not seem very good. I'd wonder if the contractor is hedging because he doesn't want to do it.